# Excel Stopwatch Time format

Tags: c#, excel, c#-2.0, excel-2003, time-format

My excel showed **00:59:49**. But when I double click it, it showed **12:59:49 AM**.

I already used formatting bit select CUSTOM and enter **hh:mm:ss**

Is there any suggestion to remove **AM** and change **12** to **00** ? Thanks.

*Since when I try to read the excel file with C#, it output wring stopwatch value.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this datetime format: **HH**:mm:ss

Comment: Hi, I also used `HH:mm:ss` style in C#. like DateTime.now.toString(HH:mm:ss); it worked quite well to transfer time format to 24hr format successfully. But It still doen't work in Excel 2003 on my laptop. :-(.